# Why am I not getting anything from my webrequest? What am I supposed to look for?

Tags: c#

First of all I am new to C#. I am writing a WPF program in Visual Studio 2019.
In my project I have multiple web requests and whilst testing how they work the functionality was minimal: only the web requests were made and they were working fine until now. The login authorization request still works.

This is my webrequest.

```
using (var client = new WebClientEx())
{
    client.BaseAddress = serverurl.serviceurl;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(excelvertibas.username + ":" + excelvertibas.password));
    
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    client.Timeout = 90000;
                    
    byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domObjectVariables));
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");//----------------
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] responseArray = client.UploadData(serverurl.serviceurl + "StartAddDigitalObject", "post", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domObjectVariables)));  //----------------------------
    domMetadataAddResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StartAddDigitalObjectResponse>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray));
}
```

The base address works, I tested it manually through Postman.

Username and password are also correct which I have tested.

Post array is also passing information which is needed, and I have checked it whilst adding breakpoints.

My question is why could this be not working anymore and what should I look for?

fyi this is the line of code where is should be getting information back into the response array but for some reason it stays null.

```
byte[] responseArray = client.UploadData(serverurl.serviceurl + "StartAddDigitalObject", "post", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domObjectVariables)));
```

After this the program breaks because the response array contains nothing when I try to pass it further.

Comment: First thing is that your `postArray` is different than the one you're sending. Is that what it should be? Because you're encoding `credentials` with ASCII and post data with UTF8

Comment: I am 90% sure that it is supposed to be like this , because the guy who wrote the test version of the programme said that his requests are working fine and his code is just like this only maybe with different variable names.And as i said the requests used to work fine when the programme was barebones and i was only testing the webrequests.

Comment: Do you have access to the server side code that you are calling or perhaps logs that are executing on the hosted server? That is where you need to debug and figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: What is the `WebClientEx`?

Comment: webclientex is the same as regular .net webclient

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have the server side code which comes out , but my coworkers told me that everything is working fine on the server side of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i understood what was the problem , when i got the response from the server , it was me who didnt provide the necessary field for the server to respond with anything.So everything was fine with the code.